# Using withCount() on a relationship that has distinct()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following models:

**Question**: [title, user_id]

**Reply**: [body, question_id, user_id]

**User**: [name]

As you can see, a question has many replies, and a reply belongs to a user.

I've added a **contributors** relationship to the **Question** model that retrieves all the users who've added a reply (using the replies as the join table):

```php
public function contributors() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'replies')->distinct('user_id');
}
```

I had to use `distinct()` to remove duplicates because a user might post many replies on a single question and this works fine.

Now the problem happens when I do:

```php
Question::withCount('contributors')->get()
```

It ignores the call to `distinct()` and gives me the total number of users who've added a reply (including duplicates).

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `distinct()` from the relationship and use `withCount()` with a raw expression:

```php
public function contributors() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'replies');
}

Question::withCount(['contributors' => function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('count(distinct(user_id))'));
}])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But I guess this can't be used with  `$withCount` property to automatically include the count, right?

Comment: Not directly, but you could set the `$withCount` property in your model's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

u can also use variable here for distinction

```
public function contributors() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'replies');
}

Question::withCount(['contributors' => function ($query) use ($var)  {
    $query->select(DB::raw('count(distinct(user_id))'));
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to continue using the distinct('user_id') in the relationship method for operations like these to work correctly:

```
$question->contributors()->count();
$question->contributors->count();
$question->contributors()->get()->count();
```

otherwise in some cases you will get different results.